# Square of normal random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be normal random variable such that $E[X] = 0$ and $Var(X) = \sigma^2 > 1$. Then what would be the distribution of $X^2$?

Answer (score 0):

It is a scaled chi square. Since $X / \sigma \sim N(0,1)$ then $X^2 /\sigma^2 \sim \chi_1^2$. Therefore, $X^2 \sim \sigma^2 \chi_1^2 $.

Comment: It is also a gamma distribution with shape parameter $2$ and scale parameter $\frac12\sigma^2$  or rate $\frac{2}{\sigma^2}$